# c# POST JSON as camel case for all requests

Tags: c#, json

I already return .Net objects as camel cased JSON and I have done this like so:

```
// Web API configuration and services
var formatters = config.Formatters;
var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
var serializerSettings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;

// Remove XML formatting
formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

// Configure our JSON output
serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
serializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

This all works fine, but today I was posting to an external API and getting an error, it turns out that the issue is with the json formatting using Pascal case instead of Camel case. My POSTed data looked like this:

```
{"CartId":"8fb3792f-81af-45e6-92f6-f08366624f1e","Id":"944990015513953203","Quantity":5}
```

I searched around and found a solution for turning that data into camel case, like this:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer()
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var json = JObject.FromObject(model, serializer);
```

but as you can guess, this is not really suitable as I don't want to have to do that in every POST action in every controller. I would have assumed that the WebApiConfig above would have applied to all responses as well as requests.

Does anyone know how I can turn on a global camel case switch?

Answer (score 5):

In this case you don't want to change it for all requests so just use attributes on your model you are sending to them.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[JsonProperty("Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

That will ensure you send it to them in the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can set global default serializer settings:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```

and now every time you serialize your model to json default settings will be used:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```