# Can I use Post request data (I mean json body) not in camel case formate for Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following controller:

```
[ApiController]
public class CheckController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/check")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Index([FromBody] CheckRequest request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have `CheckRequest` view model for binding requests:

```
public class CheckRequest
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "List of AppIds can not be empty")]
    public List<string> AppIds { get; set; }
}
```

To make request correctly I have to send something like:

[image]

And it works. I have caught my breakpoint.

But let's imagine a situation when my frontend developers (or mobile developers) tell me "No, we don't want `AppIds`, we want "app_ids"! Can you rename it?"

Now it does not work:

[image]

How I can specify in the `CheckRequest` that I need to map, for example, `app_ids` to `AppIds` parameter?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516233/c-sharp-post-json-as-camel-case-for-all-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `JsonProperty("app_ids")]` on that property to map `app_ids`

```
public class CheckRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("app_ids")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "List of AppIds can not be empty")]
    public List<string> AppIds { get; set; }
}
```

Post json body:

```
{
    "app_ids":["test1","test2"]
}
```

If you use asp.net core 3.0, you are required to add [Json.Net support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support):

1.Add nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`

2.In ConfigureServices, use

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if another mobile developer wants "ApplicationIds", you can also do this. You can now support three names.

```
public class YourObject
{
    [JsonProperty("app_ids")]
    public string AppIds{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ApplicationIds")]
    private string AppIds2 { set { AppIds = value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register below code in WEB API config. It will solve the issue.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        var serializerSettings = json.SerializerSettings;
        var contractResolver = (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver)serializerSettings.ContractResolver;
        serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        serializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
        contractResolver.IgnoreSerializableInterface = true;
        contractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there only one way? I mean maybe there is some attribute (annotation) or `nuget` package with attributes for this?